# Gradle fail to download Kotlin repository

Tags: java, maven, gradle, kotlin, jcenter

I'm building `Kotlin` simple Hello-Worl using `Gradle`

my `build.gradle` is:

```
/*
 * This build file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a commented-out sample Java project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Quickstart chapter in the Gradle
 * user guide available at https://docs.gradle.org/4.3.1/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html
 */

 // Apply the java plugin to add support for Kotlin

apply plugin: 'kotlin'


/*
plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.1.60"
}
*/

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
    repositories {
       mavenCentral()
      // jcenter()
    }
// In this section you declare the dependencies for your production and test code
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/kotlin'
    main.resources.srcDirs += 'src/resources'
}

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7'
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }

    kotlin {
        experimental {
            coroutines 'enable'
        }
    }

    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.suppressWarnings = true
    }

    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            suppressWarnings = true
        }
    }
```

and `Main.kt` is:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("kotlin!")
}
```

upon running `Gradle buil`, I got the below error:

[image]

Notes:
- I'm new to `gradle` so built it as below 2 steps:

Step 1:
[image]

Step 2:
[image]

**UPDATE**

As per the first answer, I tried getting the files locally, I created another folder named `lib` and downloaded the *.jar files into it, so I got the `gradle.build` as below:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
    repositories {
        flatDir {
           dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        classpath files('kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.1.60.jar')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'

sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/kotlin'
    main.resources.srcDirs += 'src/resources'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7'
    compile name: 'kotlin-stdlib-1.1.60'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines 'enable'
    }
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.suppressWarnings = true
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        suppressWarnings = true
    }
}
```

Below the revised structure and new error I got:

[image]

**UPDATE**

U copied all the required repositories .jar and .pom to folder:

C:\Users\.m2\repository\org\jetbrains\

I copied for example:
...\kotlin\kotlin-std\1.1.60\kotlin-stdlib-1.1.60.jar
And
...\annotations\13.0\annotations-13.0.jar

And used

mavenLocal()

But still getting the same error :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue to be with our company proxy that prevented such thing, so I solved the issue by downloading the required repository in my hole laptop then copied them to the company one.

First, I created a separate folder, named it `jars`.

After that I downloaded the required file from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.1.60) and saved it in the `jars` folder.

Then I installed it into the local repository using the command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=utility.jar -DgroupId=com.company -DartifactId=utility -Dversion=0.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Such as:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=kotlin-stdlib-1.1.60.jar -DgroupId=org.jetbrains.kotlin -DartifactId=kotlin-stdlib -Dversion=1.1.60 -Dpackaging=jar
```

**Notes:**

To do the above correctly, the `maven` is required to be downloaded from [here](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) and added to the `path`.

And command above is required to be run from the `jars` folder, that contains the downloaded repository:

[image]

Then I found that the repository had been downloaded into `C:\Users\<user>\.m2\` folder:

[image]

After copying them into my office laptop, I called them from the `mavenLocal()`:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version")
}
```

**UPDATE**

To download the full repository in one shoot instead of downloading the required files one by one, then the following command can be used:

```
mvn dependency:get -DrepoUrl=something -Dartifact=group:artifact:version
```

Such as:

```
mvn dependency:get -DrepoUrl=https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin -Dartifact=org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.60
```

For some reason 3 files failed to be downloaded, so I got them downloaded manually  and installed as per the initial explanation,the files are:

org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:jar:original:1.1.60 => [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-android-extensions/1.1.60)

org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-runner:jar:original:1.1.60 => [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-compiler-runner/1.1.60)

org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-build-common:jar:tests:1.1.60 => [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-build-common/1.1.60)

and got them installed using the below commands:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=kotlin-android-extensions-1.1.60.jar -DgroupId=org.jetbrains.kotlin -DartifactId=kotlin-android-extensions -Dversion=1.1.60 -Dpackaging=jar

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=kotlin-compiler-runner-1.1.60.jar -DgroupId=org.jetbrains.kotlin -DartifactId=kotlin-compiler-runner -Dversion=1.1.60 -Dpackaging=jar

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=kotlin-build-common-1.1.60.jar -DgroupId=org.jetbrains.kotlin -DartifactId=kotlin-build-common -Dversion=1.1.60 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Considering all the above done, the below `build.gradle` worked perfectly for me:

```
// set up the kotlin-gradle plugin
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
    repositories {
       mavenLocal()    //    mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

// apply the kotlin-gradle plugin
apply plugin: "kotlin"

// add kotlin-stdlib dependencies.
repositories {
    mavenLocal()  //  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    //dependencies from a remote repositor
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

  //local file, that are not coming from repository, let's say my own jar files
  compile files('libs/Display.jar')
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

jar {
    manifest {
        //Define mainClassName as: '[your_namespace].[your_arctifact]Kt'
        attributes ('Main-Class': 'MainKt', "Implementation-Title": "Gradle",
                   "Implementation-Version": 1)
    }
    // NEW LINE HERE !!!
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}

sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/kotlin'
    main.resources.srcDirs += 'src/resources'
}

kotlin {
    experimental.coroutines 'enable'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget= 1.8  // optional, Minimum jvmTarget of 1.8 needed since Kotlin 1.1
    kotlinOptions.suppressWarnings = true
}
```

[image]